# Get enumeration type from enumerator

Tags: c++, templates, enums

Assuming I have code like this:

```
#include <cstdio>

enum Foo { Foo_A, Foo_B };
enum Bar { Bar_A, Bar_B };

template<typename enumeration, int enumerator>
struct tpl;

template<int enumerator>
struct tpl<Foo, enumerator>
{
    tpl() { printf("Foo: %d\n", enumerator); }
};

template<int enumerator>
struct tpl<Bar, enumerator>
{
    tpl() { printf("Bar: %d\n", enumerator); }
};

int main()
{
    tpl<Foo, Foo_A> foo_a;
    tpl<Foo, Foo_B> foo_b;
    tpl<Bar, Bar_A> bar_a;
    tpl<Bar, Bar_B> bar_b;
    return 0;
};
```

Is there a way to reduce the "duplication" at the usage site? I.e. can't I deduce the enumeration type "Foo" from the enumerator "Foo_A" etc. and use that in the template code above somehow? Would an enum class help here?

Comment: This code looks like a solution to some problem. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is, *no* there currently is not a way to do this. What you are facing is known as the `template <typename T, T t>` idiom. In fact if you Google it you'll find almost 75,000 hits, and no workaround. You must specialize as you have.

---

But there is good news on the horizon. This has been proposed to the standards committee many times over the past decade:

- [N3405](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3405.html) Proposed the allowance of `template <typename T t>` Where `T` is the type and `t` is the value, only a value is passed as a template argument
- [N3601](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3601.html) Proposed that `template <typename T, T t>` be a special case where the compiler would accept only a single value as a template argument and from that would deduce `T` and `t`
- [N4469](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4469.html) Proposed that the keyword `auto` be allowed to specify a meta parameter: `template <auto t>` such that a value could be passed as template argument `t` and it's type deduced

On May 4 `15 meeting in Lenexa, N4469 finally gained traction by earning encouragement and the request for a revision in the standard committee's meeting: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4539.html#9

The first revision, [P0127R0](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/p0127r0.html), was submitted on Sep 25 '15.

A follow up revision was submitted on Mar 4 '16: [P0127R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0127r1.html) proposing edits to the Concepts working draft sections.

[P0127R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0127r2.html) focused on fully specifying the idiom change in non-Concepts sections of the working draft, as it is unclear whether Concepts will be included in C++17. This revision was accepted into the C++17 standard on Jun 23 '16: http://developerblog.redhat.com/2016/07/13/red-hat-iso-c-standards-meeting-june-2016-core-language/

So with the arrival of C++17 you will be able to dispose of the `template <typename T, T t>` idiom and use:

```
template <auto t>
struct tpl{
    tpl(){ cout << typeid(decltype(t)).name() << ": " << t << endl; }
};
```

Comment: If anyone was curious, Visual Studio uses `type_info::raw_name()` to output the mangled name, which is similar to the name GCC outputs for `type_info::name()`.

Comment: Does this mean one could overload on template type, with `f<int>()` calling a different function that `f<bool>()`?

Comment: @JimV What you're talking about is specialization (and that's possible now.) This question is about the `template <typename T, T t>` idiom. Wherein I must call `tpl<int, 13>` Even though `13` is obviously an `int`. N4469 seeks to allow us to call `tpl<13>` and be able to use that as *both* a type *and* a value template argument.

Comment: @JonathanMee: "*but this depends upon Concepts being merged into the standard*" No, it doesn't. [It's going into C++17](http://developerblog.redhat.com/2016/07/13/red-hat-iso-c-standards-meeting-june-2016-core-language/). What they did do was write *additional* wording to explain the interactions between this feature and Concepts.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thanks, for the update, I've edited. I'm really excited that this is going to make it!

Comment: Thanks a lot Jonathan for this answer. I was not aware that the thing I'm looking for is called the "template<typename T, T t>" idiom, and thus also failed to find it in my previous google attempts.

Comment: @milianw To be honest I wasn't aware either. I knew that they'd been proposing `auto` as a template type, but it didn't all click into place why that was important till I saw your question. Anyway you've obviously addressed a key issue here given the buzz this has generated with the standard committee, and I'm grateful for the opportunity to understand what's happening here, so thanks.